# Processor's characteristics C#

Tags: c#, .net, hardware, processor

Is there any way to look at your processor's characteristics using C#? Third party library, built-in Microsoft library or sth. else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using WMI. See [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1728.htm).